# why I can't use capital as the first character of the var in akka cluster distribute data example

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster, akka-actor

I am trying the official example on https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/distributed-data.html#using-the-replicator
(The first scala example on this page)
But it seems strange when I change my code a little bit.

I record a video what I change in the code .The only change I made is the name of the variable on line 16.From DataKey to dataKey. I just renamed it.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/CZrnNZlW85e9MaF73

Now the question is why it happened.
I can't use capital as the first  character of the var in this example ???
Please help me to figure that out.Thanks very much.

Akka Version:2.5.9
Scala Version:2.11.12
IDE:IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.3 Community Edition

Comment: Is there any problem when you rename the variable DataKey to dataKey ??

Comment: there should not be any problem with renaming it like you did.
but you didn't mention what was the error ? 
does it not compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the answer to the question!
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-scala-2nd/9781491950135/ch04.html

> There are a few rules and gotchas to keep in mind when writing case clauses. The compiler assumes that a term that starts with a capital letter is a type name, while a term that begins with a lowercase letter is assumed to be the name of a variable that will hold an extracted or matched value.
>
> In case clauses, a term that begins with a lowercase letter is assumed to be the name of a new variable that will hold an extracted value. To refer to a previously defined variable, enclose it in back ticks. Conversely, a term that begins with an uppercase letter is assumed to be a type name.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the pattern matching with `@`, the `@` allows you to deal with the object itself after the match. In your example, you check for the variable `c`, if that variable is an object `Changed(DataKey)` then you retrieve the `DataKey` through the method `get` on the object itself

```
 case c @ Changed(DataKey) ⇒
      val data = c.get(DataKey)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation of '@'. But Is there any problem when you rename the variable DataKey to dataKey ??

Comment: shouldn't be, but check that in your code, the dataKey variable is not in the proper colour when Changed(dataKey), so the compiler is not understanding that dataKey is the dataKey declared above. Can't see anything else in your pic :/